# Trying to build ambient type definition for typescript for a lib

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to build a ambient type definition for a js lib which is the following : https://github.com/kkemple/graphql-auth

here are my types, but this doesn't seems to work as expected

```
// Type definitions for graphql-auth
// Project: https://github.com/kkemple/graphql-auth
// Definitions by: Andréas `ScreamZ` H. <https://github.com/ScreamZ/>

export = withAuth;

declare function withAuth(resolve: Resolver): Resolver;
declare function withAuth(scopes: string[], resolver: Resolver): Resolver;

declare type Resolver = (root: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) => any
```

When i try to import in a .ts file i'm resulting with `resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.`

I know they changed declare namespace and declare module system.

I'm having issues understanding all of this.

Can someone helps me ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source file I would write the declaration like this:

```
declare module "graphql-auth" {
  export type Resolver = (root: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) => any;

  function withAuth(callback: Resolver): Resolver;
  function withAuth(scope: string[], callback: Resolver): Resolver;

  export default withAuth;
}
```

You may need to also enable [`esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#support-for-import-d-from-cjs-form-commonjs-modules-with---esmoduleinterop).